# Is excel good for data storage and analysis?

Tags: microsoft-excel, database

About a year ago I decided to store some personal information in excel file (weight, daily step count, blood pressure, books read, tasks completed, ...). Every row is one day and it's getting complicated. Is there a better solution to store and "analyse" my data? 
What I would like:

- easy daily data entry (ideally simple form filling)
- easy analysis of data
- long term data survival

Is excel good option or should I move to something else?
Thanks
Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, each day is a new record, recorded in a new row.

Say we want to start recording beginning at birth and the individual was born 18 January 1945:

[image]

Say we continued recording until all rows in a single worksheet were filled.  How old would the individual be??:

[image]

This shows that there all easily enough rows in a single sheet to do daily recordings. *(enough for 2800 years of data)*.

If your data analysis could be implemented with Excel's native tools, Excel might be a reasonable choice.

There are many free Excel templates that you can adapt to your needs.